# Assigning enum to Items

Tags: java, enums

Some background on the project: I am attempting to craft a space/sci-fi combat sim game with tabletop rpg style dice mechanics cranked up to 11 on the complexity scale, but still being transparent about the die rolls going on under the hood.  I'm currently using the Star Wars Saga Edition combat rules as a basis.

---

Currently I'm trying to figure out a way to assign traits to vehicle.(possibly stored as a class for each vehicle) Each trait is an enum so that it can store multiple pieces of information.  Here is the code I have for size categories:

```
public enum VehicleSize {
    LARGE(1,"Speeder bike",5),HUGE(2,"Small Fighter",10),GARGANTUAN(5,"Tank, Medium Fighter",20),COLOSSAL(10,"Imperial Walker, Light Freighter",50),
    COLLOSSALfrigate(10,"Corvette, Frigate",100),COLLOSSALcruiser(10,"Imperial-class Star Destroyer, Cruiser",200),
    COLLOSSALstation(10,"The Death Star, Space Station",500);

    private final int refMod;
    private final int threshMod;
    private final String desc;

    VehicleSize(int reflexModifier,String example,int thresholdModifier)
    {
        refMod = reflexModifier;
        desc = example;
        threshMod = thresholdModifier;
    }

    public int getRefMod() {
        return refMod;
    }
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public int getThreshMod() {
        return threshMod;
    }
```

}

My question is such: How do create vehicle profiles in such a way that I can assign this and similar enums as traits?

Comment: Each vehicle would have a property called `vehicleSize` of enum type `VehicleSize ` - one note, your definition of VehicleSize enum seems to describe more than just the size; So, either change the name to something more descriptive (vehicle type?) or reduce what the enum describes

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained that a bit more. The size category of the vehicle modifies its defenses and the amount of damage it can take in a single hit without getting disabled.

Comment: Then I would call it `VehicleCategory` (more descriptive) - size alone, to me, does not describe defense or damage capabilities.  It's only a suggestion and does not answer your question - (which is why I remarked it as a note)

Answer (score 0):

To add this into a class, you can use it like any user defined type.

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyEnum myEnum;
}
```

Comment: Yes.  For the most part, you can treat an enum like any other java object.  Of course, your system gets really wonky if you allow any mutation (don't even think about it).

Comment: What would be the correct way to reference the enum I showed before?  I tried the implementation below and it did not work.

    `public class XWing {
 private VehicleSize enum;
}`

Comment: You can't actually use 'enum' as a variable name, as it's a reserved word in Java.  `public class XWing {private VehicleSize size; }` should work though.

Answer (score 0):

For practically all purposes, a field whose type is an enum class is no different than a field of any other object type, like Integer or String.

Create a private field, add a getter and setter, or if the field is final (likely in your case, because a vehicle instance can't change its type), add it as a constructor parameter and remo e the setter.

```
public class Vehicle {
    private final VehicleSize vehicleSize;
    // other fields
    public Vehicle(VehicleSize vehicleSize) {
        this.vehicleSize = vehicleSize;
    }
    public VehicleSize getVehicleSize() { 
        return vehicleSize;
    }
    // rest of class
}
```

There is nothing mysterious about an enum, other than the number of different instances of it are known at compile time (and a few more things, but nothing scary).

Comment: So, It should be like this?

   `public class XWing {
 private VehicleSize GARGANTUAN;
 private Legality RESTRICTED;
 public final int cost = 150000;
 
 public XWing(VehicleSize vehicleSize){
  this.GARGANTUAN = vehicleSize;
 }
 public XWing(Legality legality){
  this.RESTRICTED = legality;
 }
 
 public VehicleSize getVehicleSize(){
  return GARGANTUAN;
 }
 public Legality getLegality(){
  return RESTRICTED;
 }
}
`

Sorry for the formatting.